# What is the exact impact of adding SSLv3 to jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in java 7 or 8

Tags: tls, java

I was trying to remove support for SSLv3 from a web app running on WebSphere 8.5/Java 7, and according to multiple sources (among others, [WebSphere Security Bulletin for CVE-2014-3566](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21687173)), I thought I could do that by adding

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

to `jre/lib/security/java.security`.

However testing with nmap and other tools showed that SSLv3 protocol is still present; and I know the setting impacts the server because I managed to disable RC4 the same way.

I tried to check the behaviour of Oracle JDK with the following code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms"));
        List<String> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders()) {
            for (Object prop : provider.keySet()) {
                String key = (String) prop;
                if (key.startsWith("SSLContext.")
                        && !key.equals("SSLContext.Default")
                        && key.matches(".*[0-9].*"))
                    protocols.add(key.substring("SSLContext.".length()));
                else if (key.startsWith("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.")
                        && key.matches(".*[0-9].*"))
                    protocols.add(key.substring("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.".length()));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(protocols);
        System.out.println(protocols);

        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    }
}
```

and running with both the latest versions of JDK 7 and 8, I can see that SSLv3 is included in the disabled algorithms, and yet also available. For instance, with JDK 8:

```
SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768
[SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
```

The first line is the current value of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`, and the second the available protocols.

So I wonder what that setting is supposed to do; as I said I know it impacts other algorithms, but why is SSLv3 reported as still available?

Thank you

Comment: You are looking at Context types, which affect protocols indirectly but are not themselves protocols. Create any (relevant) one of `SSLSocket SSLServerSocket SSLEngine` either from an explicit Context/Factory or the default one and look at `getEnabledProtocols()`.

Comment: Thank you. What's actually present is SSLv2Hello, not a full SSLv3.

Comment: Good. In case it's not clear, SSLv2Hello is basically harmless: if any client (still?!) uses SSL2 format to negotiate an acceptable protocol (TLS1.0 or higher), it works, and if anyone actually tries to negotiate SSL2 and/or SSL3 it fails but you get a specific exception something like "client requested unacceptable protocol" not a possibly more generic "protocol error".